# What's the correct parameter value of System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm joining *Hackerrank* for the first time. Just for some practise purposes.
Then, I found this line

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));
```

and pretty confused about what's the correct replacement for the `"OUTPUT_PATH"`. Because the code was copied into my IDE (Eclipse) I read the documentation but none of the reserved values suited. They all throwed NPE.

What's the correct parameter value of the `System.getenv("..")` in my case?

In case you need the full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Solution {

    /*
     * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
     */
    static int simpleArraySum(int[] ar) {
        return 2;

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //name − This is the name of the environment variable.
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int arCount = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());

        int[] ar = new int[arCount];

        String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (int arItr = 0; arItr < arCount; arItr++) {
            int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[arItr].trim());
            ar[arItr] = arItem;
        }

        int result = simpleArraySum(ar);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to replace it. That's an environment variable in the shell that is used to run your solution

Comment: Somewhere on the operating system, someone must define a variable called "OUTPUT_PATH". At runtime, your program looks at this value to decide where to write the file to.

Comment: Hi I understand. But, what if I want to try to run the code in my IDE instead? For example I can't figure it out some classes needed for particular questions, then I will need the help of my IDE.

Comment: Your code will still retrieve the environment variable from your system when run from an IDE.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: If you're on linux/osx, you can define the value of OUTPUT_PATH from the terminal... `export OUTPUT_PATH="/home/brandon/my_file.txt"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you're not supposed to replace it. That's an environment variable in the shell that is used to run your solution.

Seeing as the value of the variable is passed to `FileWriter`, this means that it represents the name of a file.

You can replicate it in a terminal by running your program with the command:

```
env OUTPUT_PATH=/path/to/some/file java Solution
```

This will start a new shell which contains a variable called `OUTPUT_PATH` pointing to a file called `/path/to/some/file` and when the program starts, the file name will be used

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone remember to compile the program first with `javac Simple.java`

Comment: Hi, I tried  `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("C:/JavaDevelopment/ujian/src/try.txt")));`, I've created the file n for some reasons it still throws NPE. But let me figure it out first.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone `System.getenv("C:/JavaDevelopment/ujian/src/try.txt")` will definitely fail unless you have defined an environment variable with the name `C:/JavaDevelopment/ujian/src/try.txt`

Comment: Ah, crab legs. I just modified it to BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(("src/try.txt"))) and it works. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone, note that the name of the variable is different from it's value. The name is what `System.getenv(...)` wants as a parameter, but the value is what you want `System.getenv(...)` to return to your `new FileWriter(...)`

Answer (score 15):

I know that this question is bit old, but maybe somebody will have benefits from this answer...

This line:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));
```

reads the environment variable defined in Hackerrank runtime/testing environment to determine the place where results will be stored for further analysis.

In order to use exactly the same code, you have to create this variable on your system and use it, or change to store results on different place (as it is already explained in previous answers and comments).

But, ...

Since this is used for a Hackerrank solving, I think it is better to have all outputs redirected to system.out instead of file, because it is far more useful to see results at runtime (or debug) in the IDE console rather than places it in a file.

So, this line is better to change on this way:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
```

which will stream your BufferedReader to System.out.

In  that case You will have same output as it is on Hackerrank  test cases, but in your IDE console instead in file.

Answer (score 4):

That "OUTPUT_PATH" is an environmental variables. You have to declare that variable in your operating system to use it. Generally website like hackerrank do it because learning the path of there system is not good for security I guess. You can test your code in IDE but the environmental variables will be not there you need to declare. I hope it helped you for your confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The question is already answered with a proper explanation. I am just adding the steps that you can simply use if your **IDE is IntelliJ IDEA**.

**Step 1:** When you run any main class in IDE, you can see there will be an option called `Edit Configurations` like this

[image: Edit Configurations]

**Step 2:** Click on Edit Configurations. On click, you will see this.

[image: Environment-Variable]

**Step 3:** Click on 3 dots that are circled in the above image. On click, you will see this.

[image: OUTPUT_PATH]

**Step 4:** Click on + symbol (as circled in the image) and add these environment variables as shown in the image. Once done click on the **Apply button** and you should be good to run your program.

This would be no different than the *Hackerrank* environment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

**In Eclipse you can set Environment variable as shown below:**

1. Right click on Java file. And, you will get eclipse context menu as shown below. Click on Run configuration.

[image]

2. In newly opened window. Click on Environment Tab. Here you can add Environment variable and value of your choice as shown in image below. Close this window.

[image]

3. Right click again on java code, click on Run, then Run as Java Application.